# How to prove that if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ absolutely convergent $\Rightarrow \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_n)^2$ convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to prove that  if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ absolutely convergent $\Rightarrow \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_n)^2$ convergent.

Do you have any idea haw can I prove it?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the proof there...:-(

Comment: One of the answers in there is mine. If there's something you don't understand in my answer, you're free to ask me there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n$ is absolutely convergent i.e. $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} |a_n|$ is convergent.

We have the result from Cauchy's criterion of convergence that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$

Thus $\exists$ $m \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $|a_n| < 1$ $\forall$ $n > m$.

Thus $(a_n)^2 < |a_n|^2 < |a_n|$

Then apply comparison test.

Let $s_k = \sum_{n = 1}^{k} |a_n|$ and $t_k = \sum_{n = 1}^{k} (a_n)^2$.

Thus $t_k < s_k$

$\{s_k\}$ is convergent as $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n$ is convergent.

So $\{t_k\}$ is also convergent.

Thus $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (a_n)^2$ is convergent.

Comment: What is the meaning of s.t.?

Comment: @YoavFridman 's.t.' is short for 'such that'.

Comment: On what I need to apply the comparison test? I didn't understand...

Comment: I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 2):

You can also say that, since $\sum a_k$ is absolutely convergent, $\sum |a_k|$ is convergent.  Let $c:=\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|$.  Then $$c^2=\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|\right)^2>\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|^2\geq \left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k^2\right|$$
(note that the last term has equality if $a_k\in\mathbb{R}$).  This means that the sum $S$ of $a_k^2$ is bounded by $|S|<c^2$ for a finite $c$.

Comment: why does sum raised at power is larger than $|a_k|^2$?

Comment: Think about distributing out the sum.  In actuality, you get $(\sum |a_k|)^2=\sum_{i,j}|a_ia_j|$. What I'm doing here is taking out all the terms in that expansion except when $i=j$, so the result must be smaller.